# ¿Por qué me da el error 'Use of unresolved identifier' cuando intento compilar para un dispositivo fisico?

Tags: swift, xcode, librería

Hice una librería en `swift` que me servirá para usar en varios proyectos `Single view app` en `iOS`.

He creado un proyecto llamado: `tripApp` solo para probar la libreria. La he agregado dando click derecho sobre el proyecto y luego en `agregar archivos a: tripApp`. Una vez agregada la arrastré a: `tripsApp -> General -> Embedded Binaries`.

Con este codigo la importo y uso.

```
import UIKit
import MiLibreria

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let mydata = Data()
       print(mydata.getData())
    }
}
```

Donde: `MiLibreria` es el nombre de la libreria. `mydata` es la variable con la que manejare lo que contenda la clase. `Data` es la clase que esta en la libreria. Y `getData` el metodo que me retornara la información que necesito de la libreria.

Cuando estoy usando un emulador, todo funciona bien. Pero el problema es, tan pronto me cambio el dispositivo fisico, me tira el error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'Data'`.

Ya no reconoce el nombre de la clase y por tanto ya no puedo acceder a su funcianalidad.

¿La libreria en swift necesita alguna configuración en especifico para que corra en el entorno de ejecucion de un dispositivo real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer tu problema surge a partir de la construcción de tu librería. Cuando se esta construyendo tu proyecto intenta vincular la aplicación para un dispositivo, no encuentra el marco creado para ese dispositivo.

Si el proyecto se compila solo en "Simulator", generaría arquitecturas que permitirían que el framework se ejecute específicamente en simuladores y no en dispositivos. O si el proyecto se compila en "Dispositivo", generaría arquitecturas que permitirían que el marco se ejecute solo en dispositivos.

Así que crea el proyecto tanto en "Simulador" como en "Dispositivo".

Te adjunto una liga donde se contesta está pregunta [stackoverflow respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516568/swift-framework-build-fails-for-device-but-not-for-simulator)

Comment: ¡Exactamente ese era el problema! Nunca me habría pasado por la cabeza. Muchas gracias.